# Change timeout of request with angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently using rxjs and httpclient from angular to make a get request. It looks something like this:

```
  get<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http
      .get<T>(path, { headers: this.httpOptions.headers })
      .pipe(timeout(5000), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

But my requests always get cacelled if the're past one second duration.

I've tried to send the `timeout: 5000` in the headers, it did not work.

Then I tried to sendo the timeout(5000) method inside the pipe(), but that didn't work either.

I cannot edit the API to shorten the response time.

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated?

Answer (score -1):

You are not using [`timeout`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) operator correctly. You have to provide a backup observable in case the original one fails to emit something during the given timeout period.

So, you would have the following piece of code:

```js
get<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
    const request$ = this.http.get<T>(path, { headers: this.httpOptions.headers });

    return request$.pipe(
      timeout({
        each: 5000,
        with: () => throwError(() => new CustomTimeoutError()) //throw an error in case of timeout, or other observable
      }), 
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Request timed out or encountered an error:', error); // Handle timeout or other errors
        return of(null); 
      })
    );
 }
```

You can throw a custom error in case of timeout, or switch to a different observable (a backup endpoint).

Hope this helps you! :)